# Wireless Throttled

Tags: 14.04, wireless, internet

I've recently got installed a line of 300Mbps. The first test was 4 days ago and the real speed was 180Mbps (ookla speed test).
However, it's some day that the speed is diminished... a lot! Now the same test, with the same server selected, output something like 30~40Mbps. Doing the same test on windows (same notebook), give a result of 214Mbps!
Some update screwed up? How can I revert to the older wireless driver?

I'm on an Asus ROG g750JZ, with Ubuntu 14.04

Below you can find the result of wireless_script, as suggested by @Fabby:

[wireless-info](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10903588/) | [mirror](http://www.mediafire.com/download/ogdy0rc7mgc4tug/wireless-info.tar.gz)

---

**UPDATE:**

I don't know if can be of any help, but Win8.1 use the Qualcomm Atheros Wireless Lan Driver, v1.0.37.1274 (... or maybe 10.0.0.287, I'm not sure)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after a bit of searching, I found the problem wasn't in the driver or in Ubuntu, but in the router itself. If I understood it correctly, it can emit a 2.4 (b/g) or a 5GHz (a/n) signal, but only the latter is suitable for a 300Mbs connection. I think the algorithm just chooses the one more stable, with less noise. The router came bundled with the connection I have contacted the support service; they said they will soon release a firmware update to allow disabling the 2.4 channels.

Hence, if you are experiencing something similar, check the frequency with:

```
iwlist wlan0 freq | tail -n 1
```

And ensure that the channel is >= 36!

Answer (score 0):

You can narrow things down by downloading Kali Linux on a USB drive and boot from it. If the test goes well, you will know that it is the problem with your setup, and not with the fact that you have a Linux OS.

Comment: By "test" i ment "speed test"
I had a similar problem with the Ubuntu installation on my laptop. I had this USB stick with Kali on it so I booted from it to check if the wifi card will be detected and set up correctly. Everything worked fine, so i new it was not a hardware issue, and not related to Linux.

Comment: Good point, I will do this check ASAP!